# Upgrade python 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python

I have two versions of python, namely, 2.7.10 and 3.4.3 in my Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) machine.

How can I upgrade the 3.4.3 version to 3.5 latest version without affecting the 2.7.10 version?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Use this command on your ubuntu shell (not on the python prompt).

```
sudo apt upgrade python3
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee which version you get, it just upgrades to whichever version is the newest in the repos in your Apt `sources.list`.